# Securing SQL injection for my PHP files

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

I have made a PHP forum. I used PDO, as well as SQLi. When I did a security scan of my website, it found errors, and after a long time of trying different stuff, I can't fix them.

Points to whomever help me fix them.

I got the following errors:

**sql injection**
Classification Input:  Validation Error 
Resource:   view_topic.php
Parameter:  id
Method:  GET

**sql injection**
Classification Input:  Validation Error 
Resource:   add_answer.php
Parameter:  a_email
Parameter:  a_answer
Parameter:  a_name
Parameter:  id
Method:  GET

**Integer overflow**
Classification: Boundary Condition Error
Resource: view_topic.php?id=2147483647
Parameter: id
Method: GET

**Integer overflow**
Classification: Boundary Condition Error
Resource: view_topic.php?id=2147483647
Parameter: id
Method: GET

**Cross site scripting**
Classification: Input Validation Error
Resource: view_topic
Resource: /add_answer.php
Parameter: id
Method: GET

**PHP FILES** 
 
***add_answer.php***

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="linux"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="simpleFourm"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="fanswer"; // Table name 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


// Get value of id that sent from hidden field 
$id=$_POST['id'];

// Find highest answer number. 
$sql="SELECT MAX(a_id) AS Maxa_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE question_id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 

$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

// add + 1 to highest answer number and keep it in variable name "$Max_id". if there no answer yet set it = 1 
if ($rows) {
$Max_id = $rows['Maxa_id']+1;
}
else {
$Max_id = 1;
}

// get values that sent from form 
$a_name=$_POST['a_name'];
$a_email=$_POST['a_email'];
$a_answer=$_POST['a_answer']; 

$datetime=date("d/m/y H:i:s"); // create date and time

// Insert answer 
$sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(question_id, a_id, a_name, a_email, a_answer, a_datetime)VALUES('$id', '$Max_id', '$a_name', '$a_email', '$a_answer', '$datetime')";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2); 

if($result2){
echo "Successful<BR>";
echo "<a href='view_topic.php?id=".$id."'>View your answer</a>";

// If added new answer, add value +1 in reply column 
$tbl_name2="fquestions";
$sql3="UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET reply='$Max_id' WHERE id='$id'";
$result3 = $conn->query($sql3); 

}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// Close connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

***view_topic.php***

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="linux"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="simpleFourm"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="fquestions"; // Table name 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 

$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bordercolor="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong><?php echo $rows['topic']; ?></strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['detail']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>By :</strong> <?php echo $rows['name']; ?> <strong>Email : </strong><?php echo $rows['email'];?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Date/time : </strong><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
<BR>

<?php

$tbl_name2="fanswer"; // Switch to table "forum_answer"
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE question_id='$id'";
$result2  = $conn->query($sql2);

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($rows = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Answer</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_answer']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table><br>

<?php
  }
} else {
    echo "<font color='red'>0 results</font>" ; 

}


$sql3="SELECT view FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result3 = $conn->query($sql3);

$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result3);


$view=$rows['view'];

// if have no counter value set counter = 1
if(empty($view)){
$view=1;

$sql4="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(view) VALUES('$view') WHERE id='$id'";
$result4 = $conn->query($sql4);

}

// count more value
$addview=$view+1;
$sql5="update $tbl_name set view='$addview' WHERE id='$id'";
$result5  = $conn->query($sql5);
$conn->close();
?>

<BR>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="add_answer.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td width="18%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td width="3%">:</td>
<td width="79%"><input name="a_name" type="text" id="a_name" size="45"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="a_email" type="text" id="a_email" size="45"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><strong>Answer</strong></td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><textarea name="a_answer" cols="45" rows="3" id="a_answer"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php`, `http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php` (see the examples).

Comment: Many points were already given to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/480536)

Comment: [Same question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31612278/53114) got closed as a duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114)

Comment: You’re using [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) and not [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When talking about SQL injection, regardless of language, you should use parametrized queries. These construct a query plan ahead of time, rather than when the user provides input, so an attacker cannot easily modify how the query works.

PHP supports this, but you need to use the PDO library rather than the `mysqli` functions. http://php.net/pdo for more information. It does take more work than simple queries with mysqli, but you get SQLi protection by using parametrized queries, and it's a good practice to start doing.

Secondly, you should not use MySQL's `root` user to connect to your database. Defense in depth practices include running an application with as few permissions as you need. And I really hope that isn't your root password to your database.

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP’s database features are quite rudimentary/low level, just PHP wrappers for the DBMS API. There is no convenient way like `$x->exec('SELECT * FROM x WHERE y=?', $_POST['z']);`. Instead you have to do everything (preparing, parameter binding/assignment, execution) on your own.